# How do I make the DDMS native heap tab visible?

Tags: android, ddms

I have read online about the native heap tab, however I do not see the tab in my DDMS view. My question is, how do I make this tab visible so that I can see an overview of the native heap usage of my app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ddms tool seems to not support native heap debugging anymore after android sdk revision 19 or 20.

So to get the native heap view tap in the ddms tool, download the old tools via:
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository/tools_r18-windows.zip (similar links for other plaforms)

You should be able to reuse your current sdk folder (latest version). But rename your current sdk/tools folder to something like sdk/tools_backup. So you can switch back to it for building with eclipse etc. after debugging.

Now create a new tools folder and copy the content  of the downloaded zip file into it.

You can start the ddms tool directly from the tools folder.
If you followed the steps from mercury (native=true) in the ddms.cfg of your user_directory/android/ you should be able to see the native heap tab.

Have fun debugging :)

PS.: Of course you need a device setup that replaces libc.so with libc_malloc_debug.so. you can find tutorials via google.

Answer (score 0):

Open ~/.android/ddms.cfg
Add a line "native=true"
Upon relaunching DDMS and selecting a process, you can switch to the new native allocation tab and populate it with a list of allocations.